# sqlite- fetch data from multiple tables together- android and iOS

Tags: javascript, typescript, sqlite, ionic3

I have multiple sqlite tables and I want to fetch data from these tables together from Ionic 3 app for android and iOS platform and send it to server

Here's the code I wrote for this functionality

```
function fetchDataFromSqlite(){
let tableNames = ['table1','table2','table3'];
var dataFromSQLite= {};

for (var i = 0; i < tableNames.length; i++)
{
   let tableName = tableNames[i];
   let queryParams = [1];
   let query = `SELECT * FROM ${tableName} WHERE status= ?`; 
   this.databaseprovider.SelectQry(query, queryParams).then(data => {
     dataFromSQLite[tableName] = data;
   });
  return dataFromSQLite;
}
}
```

Above function is what I wrote to perform this action. I call this function in my app component

`SelectQry()` in `databaseprovider` looks like this:

```
  SelectQry(sql, params) {
    return this.database.executeSql(sql, params).then(
      data => {
        return data;
      },
      err => {
        console.log("Error: ", JSON.stringify(err));
        return [];
      }
    );
  }
```

When I `alert()` the data returned from `fetchDataFromSqlite()` , I get `{}`

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or why I'm not getting any output when there's data in SQLite tables?

Comment: just a hint , use TypeOrm it will save alot of time with sql .